# Didn't get in-app purchase server to server notification?

Tags: django, in-app-purchase, webhooks, server-to-server

I implement in-app purchase server to server notification and add url in appstore But Some time i didn't get response from apple server in sandbox environment. My backend is in Python - django. Can anyone help me how to implement?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what software you have already created or the idea you are asking help with in the question?

Comment: Please add more details to this question so the SO community can provide more targeted assistance. Otherwise you will get a breadth of answers, many of which will be right in specific conditions only.

Answer (score 0):

I think to solve this question you're going to need to give more context.

I assume you've got a Django serverand and a (node.js) express api that is pointing to it for purchases:

If that's the case you'll need to create the routes in your express api for the in-app purchase function you need. There are many tutorials on this online that you could follow, type in express REST api into youtube.

Then call that api in your Django server using the request library, where you need it.

Comment: I need solution in any platform. I am creating one post request for in app purchase server to server notification but i didn't get response body from apple. so i need solution for this in either node or in django.

Comment: You need to look at the apple documenation and check what they are sending from there api to solve your issue. Then simple use fetch in node to access the api, or post it from apple to your api's get function.

Comment: I check but i didn't get any thing.

Comment: Then check if you are using authentication required, may be a code you need to be sending, or check the code inside your express function

Answer (score 0):

#### Simplest Server to Server Approach using API

When an in-app purchase takes on say `Server A`, you can call an endpoint on say `Server B` where there is a listener who receive data which you will send from `Server A`.

This will work as a webhook for you.

If this doesn't help, please state your full or a bit more descriptive problem.